# Shrink and center a bunch of dynamically generated images within a container

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

Just wondering how I can shrink and center a bunch of dynamically generated images within a container.

Preface: I am not the designer.

I want the page to end up looking like this:[image: mockup]
This is what it currently looks like:
http://www.nickysfolders.com/nicky-s-communicator-english.aspx?SessionThemeID=34

This is my css:

```
.product-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 23vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.cent {
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

this is my html:

```
<div class="product-wrapper">
<div class="cent">
            <ac:layoutarea id="PhotoArea">
              <a href="$$LINKHREF$$" itemprop="image" class="main-product-photo block zoom rel">
                $$MAINPHOTO$$
                <!--<div class="caption">$$CAPTION$$</div>-->
              </a>
              <ac:visibilityarea id="lvCarousel">
                <div class="pad-20 no-pad-lr">
                  $$THUMBNAILS$$
                </div>
              </ac:visibilityarea>
            </ac:layoutarea>
            <ac:layoutarea id="PhotoThumbLayout">
              <ul class="product-thumbnails no-padding">$$GROUP$$</ul>
            </ac:layoutarea>
            <ac:layoutarea id="PhotoThumbGroup">
              $$ITEM$$
            </ac:layoutarea>
            <ac:layoutarea id="PhotoThumb">
              <li class="no-padding"><a href="$$THUMBLINKHREF$$" class="thumbnail">$$THUMBNAIL$$</a></li>
            </ac:layoutarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="Featured">
              <div class="abs product-flag left top featured"><span>Featured!</span></div>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="Spotlight">
              <div class="abs product-flag left bottom spotlight"><span>Spotlight!</span></div>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="Flag1">
              <div class="abs product-flag right top flag1"><span>New!</span></div>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="Flag2">
              <div class="abs product-flag right bottom flag2"><span>Hot!</span></div>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="Flag3">
              <div class="abs product-flag right bottom flag3"><span>Sale!</span></div>
            </ac:visibilityarea>

</div>
</div>
```

I am working within a hosted cms called americommerce, please save me.

Let me know if I can provide anything else that may be useful.

Thank you friends.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your site. All you would have to do is just add a 
`text-align:center;` to your `.cent` class.